# How to fix Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am still a newbie in Hyperledger.
I have a problem when trying to create and join channel.

I type in Docker Quickstart Terminal `peer channel create -o orderer.medrecnet.com:7050 -c medrecnetChannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls –cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.medrecnet.com-cert.pem`

After that I got error

> 2019-02-19 11:25:49.715 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer
>   because cannot init crypto, folder
>   "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp"
>   does not exist

I have followed the step from https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html?highlight=script.sh

This is my docker-compose-cli.yaml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.medrecnet.com:
  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:  

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.medrecnet.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.medrecnet.com
    container_name: orderer.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=HospitalMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.medrecnet.com
      - peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
      - peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

This is my docker-compose-base.yaml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: orderer.medrecnet.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    - orderer.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=HospitalMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=doctorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.medrecnet.com/peers/peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.medrecnet.com/peers/peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

Comment: did you export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS before executing the command?

Comment: I have done that by export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.hospital.medrec.com:7051 and also export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp. But the error is still happening.

Comment: I have modified docker-compose-cli.yaml at line CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH. Before --> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer. Now become --> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp.